# How to fix HTML comment in Next.js <title>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

We have the following code in next.js page:

```js
   <Head>
        <title>
          Some text {title}
        </title>
   </Head>
```

For a split second, I see html comment like <!--- ---> (something like that)

I use static site generation (getServerSideProps), and my file has a dynamic route, like [id], so I also use getStaticPaths.

What do I do?

Answer (score 13):

Here's the answer.

For some reason, Next.js doesn't like us writing inside  like this Static text {dynamicText}

What we should do instead is write it like this:

```
<title>{`Static text${dynamicText}`}</title>
```

You first write {}, then you pass backticks (``) inside of it. Inside these backticks, you use template literals. Here you can write whatever you want, be it static or dynamic text. Just make sure to write **nothing** outside of it. Only inside the string.

Hope that helps everyone who has experienced the same issue.

Comment: What a bizarre quirk! Thanks for writing up the answer.

Comment: Literally just experienced this same thing. +1 buddy 